# Positive(semi-)definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Be $m,n\ge 1$, be $A\in\mathrm{Sym} _m(\mathbb{R})$, $B\in \mathrm{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $C\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ furthermore [image]

with $\det(A)\neq 0$ and be $S:=B-C^t*A^{-1}*C$.

It's to proof that:

$M$ positive(semi-) definite $\Leftrightarrow A$ and $S$ positive(semi-) definite

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated as we got this as a voluntary task and won't get any solution, but I would still love to understand it, because as of now I don't really have a clue on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is called the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

With some computation you can show that $M$ is similar to
$$\begin{bmatrix}A \\ & S\end{bmatrix}.$$
(The Wikipedia page does it for the Schur complement of the bottom right block rather than of the upper left block, but the computation is similar.)

So $M$ is P[S]D if and only if both $A$ and $S$ are P[S]D.